# Curved header with CSS where the curve does not scale weird with different height and width changes (responsive)

Tags: css, css-shapes

I have found multiple questions answered on stackoverflow how to create a curved header but none answer my specific problem. These days responsive design is a must but I have not found a way to incorporate a curved header where the curve stays the same no matter the width or height.

See the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v6cz2mqb/) I have created where the border-radius stays the same in 3 examples of a curved header but based on different widths and heights of the container the curve changes. Opening the dev tools and toggling the device toolbar shows even better how ugly this would look on smaller screens where the curve almost turns into a circle.

I have created a curved header that looks perfect on desktop but once the screen starts to get smaller it just starts to look ugly and circle like. Is it possible to have a curved header in CSS or with other techniques where the curve stays the same no matter width of screen or height of header?

```css
body{
  background-color:#f3f2f4;
}
.header{
  width:100%;
  height:30%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#8459f9, #4c3196);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 20%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 20%;
}
.container{
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
}


.header2{
  width: 100%;
  height:30%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#8459f9, #4c3196);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 20%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 20%;
}
.container2{
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 500px;
  width: 150px;
  background: red;
}

.header3{
  width:100%;
  height:30%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#8459f9, #4c3196);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50% 20%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50% 20%;
}
.container3{
  margin-top: 10px;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
  <div class="header">
  </div>  
 </div>
 
  <div class="container2">
  <div class="header2">
  </div>  
 </div>
 
 <div class="container3">
  <div class="header3">
  </div>  
 </div>
```

Comment: Since the dimensions of your containers change, the calculated curve changes. you cannot have the same curve with a taller element, if that makes sense.
Height/width ratio of your purple element needs to stay the same to produce the same curve

Comment: @Lalalena I understand, but I'm searching for a way to keep the curve the same no matter the height or width. I understand that it is not possible with the current CSS. I'm hoping someone could point me in the right direction on how it is possible

Comment: You could split your element into two - a div with background-color that serves as the top purple portion, and the curved div that's the bottom purple portion - and the bottom div has the same proportional measurements for all screen sizes, if that makes sense.
I haven't looked into it, but maybe css mask would be an option too, if you want to go that way?
Else you are going to have to calculate your curve based on element dimensions, probably by using css ```calc()```or something similar